# Live website powered by CppCMS

Tags: c++, frameworks, cppcms

CppCMS looks fine for me.. but do you know any live website powered by CppCMS?

Answer (score 11):

First of all take a look on this page: http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/who_uses

There are several known users:

- Several services provided by **dhiti** like: http://dive.dhiti.com/ use CppCMS
- Some new services on [Lifeix](http://www.l99.com) use CppCMS and CppDB
- [Page2RSS](http://page2rss.com) uses CppCMS for their fronted.
- http://tatoeba.org is developing a new version of the web site that uses CppCMS (that is on its alpha stage): http://tato.sysko.fr/eng
- CppCMS's website build on CppCMS also CppCMS author's blog is build on CppCMS as well - runs for several years very well.
- There are several companies using CppCMS in their embedded products.

And there are more.

Artyom (CppCMS's author)

Answer (score 6):

Fo example, CppCMS's own [website](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main) is built with it. The author is eating his own dogfood...